# Why does my figure break when I add a label in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to draw a simple triangle, and label the lengths of each side, and I'm trying to use tikz.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,thick] (0, 0) -- node[below]{\(1\)} ++ (1, 0);
    \draw[black,thick] (0, 0) -- node[left]{\(1\)} ++ (0, 1);
    \draw[black,thick] (1, 0) -- (0, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That works, and produces a triangle with labels as expected:

[image: Screenshot of triangle where all sides of the triangle expect the hypotenuse are labeled]

However, when I try to add a label to the hypotenuse by changing the third `\draw` statement to `\draw[black,thick] (1, 0) -- node[above right]{\(\sqrt{2}\)} ++ (0, 1);`, I get this:

[image: Screenshot of broken triangle]

The label is admittedly above it and to the right, but my triangle is... no longer a triangle. How can I fix this so it looks more like this (that drawing is to represent how I'd like the label/lines to be placed - I'd use the proper `\( ... \)` for the label, of course)

[image]

How can I correct my LaTeX to properly display my triangle with labels on all three sides?

Comment: Welcome! You did not only add the node, you added a `++` that is transforming the `(0,1)` from absolute to relative...

Comment: @Rmano Removing the `++` fixed it; thank you!

Comment: @cocomac Try drawing a triangle as a triangle and not as three separate lines: `\draw[black, thick, auto=right] (0, 1) -- node{1} (0, 0) -- node{1} -- node{$\sqrt 2$} cycle;`

Comment: cocomac notice that the @Qrrbrbirlbel comment is important. Try to just remove the `++` and then zoom on the vertices...

Answer (score 2):

With `quote` library and absolute coordinates:

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\draw[thick] (0,0) to["\(1\)"]          (2,0)
                   to["\(\sqrt{2}\)"]   (0,2)
                   to["\(1\)"]          cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and with relative coordinates:

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\draw[thick] (0,0) to["\(1\)"]          ++ ( 2,0)
                   to["\(\sqrt{2}\)"]   ++ (-2,2)
                   to["\(1\)"]          cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the both cases result is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This code gives two options the correct triangle and node labeling. The upper one uses your style of labeling, the lower one is the one Qrrbrbirlbel mentioned (including the missing node in his comment).

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[black,thick] (0,0) -- node[below] {\(1\)}  (1,0) -- node[above right]{\(\sqrt{2}\)}  (0,1) -- node[left]{\(1\)}  cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black, thick, auto=right] (0, 1) -- node{1} (0, 0) -- node{1}(1,0) -- node{$\sqrt 2$} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In your code you actually created a rectangle when you use the code

`\draw[black,thick] (0,0) -- node[below]{\(1\)} ++ (1,0);`

You place the left corner in location (0,0) and extend the rectangle with 1 unit wide and 0 units height. That is what the addition `++` after the node means. So you don't draw *lines* that define a triangle, but *blocks* of 0 thickness.

Using the `cycle` command at the end of the code, tells tikz you are drawing a closed figure, that eventually also can be filled with a color.

Comment: (alternatively just remove the `++`. Same result.) // The explanation about "blocks of 0 thickness" is actually wrong, it just draw a line to the specified coordinate. Try something like `++(-1, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks @user202729 learned another thing about ‘tikz’ 

Answer (score 0):

With `tkz-euclide`

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,1/0/B,0/1/C}
        \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,B,C)
        \tkzLabelSegment(A,B){$1$}
        \tkzLabelSegment[auto=right](B,C){$\sqrt{2}$}
        \tkzLabelSegment[left](C,A){$1$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```